# Flat file data export - fixed column length if numeric field is null

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, data-extraction, utl-file

I have a temporary table holding application data I wish to export into a flat file with fixed positions. What I am struggelig with is that some of the values in numeric column account_numbers is null. During export the null value rows are not replaced with space but rather set as null. I suspected I have to convert the column to char prior to padding but it does not seem to resolve the issue.
What am i missing?

RPAD(To_char(i.Account_Number),11,' ')

**Create table insert data:**

```
create table V_APPLICATION_INSTANCE
(
  account_number NUMBER(19),
  created_date   TIMESTAMP(6),
  decision       VARCHAR2(40),
  name           VARCHAR2(40)
);

insert into V_APPLICATION_INSTANCE (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CREATED_DATE, DECISION, NAME)
values (1679669315, '09-SEP-16 10.43.51.932000 AM', 'APPROVED', 'TAF2214');

insert into V_APPLICATION_INSTANCE (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CREATED_DATE, DECISION, NAME)
values (null, '31-AUG-16 12.41.53.331000 PM', 'APPROVED', 'TAF2234');

insert into V_APPLICATION_INSTANCE (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CREATED_DATE, DECISION, NAME)
values (1528296849, '02-SEP-16 12.00.32.008000 PM', 'APPROVED', 'TAF1234');

insert into V_APPLICATION_INSTANCE (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CREATED_DATE, DECISION, NAME)
values (null, '31-AUG-16 05.05.30.433000 PM', 'APPROVED', 'TAF1234');
```

**Export to flat file:**

```
Declare
  pFile Utl_File.file_type;
  fLine Varchar2(1024);

Begin

  pFile := UTL_FILE.fopen('USER_TEMP', 'APPLIC_EXPORT.txt', 'w');

  For i in (Select V.ACCOUNT_NUMBER ,V.CREATED_DATE,TRIM(V.DECISION) DECISION,TRIM(V.NAME) NAME From V_APPLICATION_INSTANCE V) 
  Loop

    fLine := RPAD(i.Account_Number,11,' ') || ' ' || RPAD(i.Created_Date,30,' ') || ' ' ||
             RPAD(i.Decision,25,' ') || ' ' || RPAD(i.Name,50,' ');
    UTL_FILE.put_line(pFile, convert(fLine, 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'UTF8'));

  End Loop;

  UTL_FILE.fclose(pFile);
End;
```

**Output:**

```
 ===================================================== == == == =========== == == == == == == == == == ===== 
  1679669315  09-SEP-16 10.43.51.932000 AM   APPROVED              TAF2214                                   
   31-AUG-16 12.41.53.331000 PM   APPROVED                 TAF2234                                   
  1528296849  02-SEP-16 12.00.32.008000 PM   APPROVED              TAF1234                                   
   31-AUG-16 05.05.30.433000 PM   APPROVED                 TAF1234                                   
 ===================================================== == == == =========== == == == == == == == == == =====
```

**Expected result:**

```
 ===================================================== == == == =========== == == == == == == == == == ===== 
  1679669315  09-SEP-16 10.43.51.932000 AM   APPROVED              TAF2214                                   
              31-AUG-16 12.41.53.331000 PM   APPROVED              TAF2234                                   
  1528296849  02-SEP-16 12.00.32.008000 PM   APPROVED              TAF1234                                   
              31-AUG-16 05.05.30.433000 PM   APPROVED              TAF1234                                   
 ===================================================== == == == =========== == == == == == == == == == =====
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer my own question, but i finally found the solution.
Had to replace null with space

rpad(nvl(TO_CHAR(i.account_number), ' '),11,' ')